# Propagator for fermion fields and Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, fermions

I need some help concerning the interpretation of propagators and Feynman diagrams.

The free fermion propagator is given by the contraction of two fields $\psi(x),\bar\psi(y)$:

$D_F(x-y)=T\{\psi(x)\bar\psi(y)\}$

In this notation, the arrow in the Feynman diagram linking $x$ and $y$ will go from  $x$ to $y$ or the opposite?

Comment: Where the arrow points is a matter of convention. Doesn't matter what you do, as long as you are consistent.

Comment: Can you please be more explicit? If we denote an anti-particle with an arrow going in the opposite direction of the momentum, what is the answer?